# loopback authentication with the third party

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have been provided with client ID and client secret along with username and password and an URL to do a post request on. I would like to make a post request to that URL and do authentication to get `accessToken` which can be used to access endpoints. I cannot figure out where to set it. How to do this in loopback3?

I have tried following the loopback3 doc...login in with the third party but I seem to get lost.

Comment: Which third party are you integrating with?

Comment: you can check how loopback can be integrated with auth0 [here](https://auth0.com/blog/developing-restful-apis-with-loopback/).

Comment: @rodrigoap am intergrating ith another app which has already done the oauth. Mine is to hit the url and get back the accessToken...am supplied with client id client secret, username and password plus the token url...something like this :the user has full access
https://felix.jambo.co.ke/oauth/token
send a post request containing the following fields 
  grant_type=password, 
  client_id=3
  client_secret=NAHnFriBo8DSsKSTzrwkIbSGXXhteF4xSyPNrUut
  username=felix@jambo.co.ke
  password=pass123